# How to run a Data Import Script in Seprate Thread Grails/Grrovy?

Tags: multithreading, grails, groovy

I use to import data from excel ,but i use the bootstrap.groovy to write the code and my import script method is called when the application starts.

Here the scenarios is i m having 8000 related data once to import if they are not on my database.And,also when i deploy it to tomcat6 it is blocking other apps from deployment ,until it finish  the import.So,i want to use separate thread for to run the script in anyway without affecting performance AND BLOCKING OTHER FROM DEPLOYMENT.

code excerpt ...

```
class BootStrap {

    def grailsApplication
    def sessionFactory

    def excelService

def importStateLgaArea(){


        String fileName = grailsApplication.mainContext.servletContext.getRealPath('filename.xlsx')
        ExcelImporter importer = new ExcelImporter(fileName)
        def listState = importer.getStateLgaTerritoryList() //get the map,form excel
        log.info "List form excel:${listState}"

        def checkPreviousImport = Area.findByName('Osusu')
        if(!checkPreviousImport) {
        int  i = 0
        int j = 0 // up

    date cases
            def beforeTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            for(row in listState){

                def state = State.findByName(row['state']) 
                if(!state) {
                //  log.info "Saving State:${row['state']}"
                    row['state'] = row['state'].toString().toLowerCase().capitalize()
                //  log.info "after capitalized" + row['state']
                    state = new State(name:row['state'])
                    if(!state.save(flash:true)){
                        log.info "${state.errors}"  
                        break;
                    }           
                }

}
}
```

Comment: Can you show some of the code..?

Comment: what do you mean ? you think that am lame right :)

Comment: No one out here is lame man... By adding some code u just improved your question and got someone answering it as well...

Answer (score 0):

For import of large data I suggest to take in consideration the use of [Spring Batch](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/). Is easy to integrate it in grails. You can try with [this plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-batch) or integrate it manually.

Comment: Spring Batch take care of multithread. It organize work in jobs and task and you can simpli configure concurrency level (1 at time, 2 at a time, n at a time) ecc...